# MongoClient constructor with seeds

Tags: java, mongodb, database-replication

Suppose I have a replica set with one primary `P` and three secondaries `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`. Suppose an application creates a Mongo clent with this [constructor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#MongoClient%28java.util.List%29). The *seeds* list is {`P`,  `S1`, `S2`}. Note the list does not contain `S3`.

Suppose the application uses `secondPreferred` and both `S1` and `S2` are down. Will the queries go to `P` or `S3` ?

The javadoc says `It will find all members (the master will be used by default)`, and I guess the queries will go to `S3`. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seed list is exactly that, the driver will query that list to understand the map of the replica set. This means it can actually use members NOT on that list, i.e. it can use `S3`.

When the driver has to detect a change in the replica set, either by failover or by starting up it will query one of the members of the seed list for basically a `rs.status()` and it will store the result in itself for a time that the driver deems worthy to refresh it, or something happens that forces the driver to refresh it (i.e. failover).

So the answer is yes, it will go for `S3`.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it looks like there is no difference between {P} and {P, S1, S2, S3} seeds. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Michael The general **best** practice is to have enough **seeds** in the connection in order that if nodes are down then there is something that can tell you *which* nodes are **up**. In the specific case you mentioned, requests would go to `S3` even if *unseeded* because `P` was up and knew about `S3` as a member. But this is still not **guaranteed** just by `secondaryPreferred` alone.  The rest depends on your configuration. So requests **may** go to `P` in preference. It all depends on how you are set up.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for the explanation. Could you give an example of the scenario, when queries with `secondPreferred` and no tags will go to `P` if `S3` is up ?

Comment: @Michael Um Nope. And going back to your original line of questions. What **you** can do, as we will **only** do if we are *really* bored, have lack of life etc, is configure up a *test* replica set locally and **test** your expected code results against that configuration before screaming **bug**. Remember, treat people on **SO** as **busy** knowledgeable colleagues, and the more **work** you put into your questions, the more likely we will be to offer some assistance.

Comment: @NeilLunn First of all I would like to thank you for your answers on SO. It helps me out a lot. As for my previous question, I am just confused because the API doesn't work as I expected. I will probably edit that question: `s/bug/results I do not expect/understand/g`.

Comment: @Michael what does it actually do?

Comment: @Michael I mean this is the dirty internals of how it should work: http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/connect-driver-to-replica-set/